# How can I dehumidify a room without a dehumidifier?

Tags: home, air

I was reading [How can I humidify a room without a humidifier?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/10767/1443), and it got me curious.

I live in Florida where the humidity is insane. Dehumidifiers cost hundreds of dollars. What is a cheaper alternative to dehumidify a small room (about 10x10)?

Comment: Note, only gerb's answer would apply to this question.

Answer (score 0):

An ordinary air conditioner dehumidifies the air as it cools.  If you don't need cooling, you can let the machine's hot air exhaust mix with the cold, and you'll get a slight heating effect, but the water will still be pulled out of the air by condensation on the cold evaporator coils.

You can get small air conditioners for under $100, though you might have to improvise a bit in terms of mounting to use it this way.

Answer (score -1):

You can get a portable dehumidifier. It doesn't cost that much. I have one and it works well for a single room. The one I got is this [Ivation dehumidifier from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KWKONAG)

It looks like this: [image]

Turning on AC in the summer and turning on furnace(electric heater) in the winter also helps reduce humidity in the room.